# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() is returning null

Tags: null, classpath, tools.jar, javacompiler

I have tried everything like included `tools.jar` file in my `classpath` like

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.0.0.82\lib\tools.jar" SourceFile [ ( Paramters ) ]
```

Also i tried to copy `tools.jar` to my `classpath` where my binary files like `javac`, `java`, etc. are located but `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` is still returning `null`.

Please help me to make my code work.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy tools.jar file from /lib to It works

You can obtain by System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.home"))

Most of time it is like C:\Program files\Java\jre(version) [ for windows ]